# Как правильно настроить locations в nginx за балансировщиком?

Tags: nginx, proxy

Схема примерно следующая: Есть example.com, состоящий из нескольких приложений - сайт на php и java приложения для личного кабинета. В данный момент для кабинета настроен поддомен и все работает - там один location, который проксируется сразу на java приложение.

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://cabinet/;
}
```

Но появилась необходимость вывести приложение из поддомена и сделать доступ по url: `example.com/cabinet`.

Если использовать настройки ниже, то `example.com/cabinet` открывается без стилей и js. Дело в том, что в самом java приложении есть пути вида `/static/jqery.js` - на которые выдает 404 и стили не грузятся. Часть сайта на php работает нормально. Сейчас ссылки ведут на php сайт `example.com/static/script.js`. Возможно ли сделать, так чтобы при заходе на `/cabinet` все ссылки на статичные файлы были вида `example.com/cabinet/static/script.js` ?

```
# Сервера с php приложением
upstream php {
ip_hash;
server 192.168.100.20 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=360 weight=10;
server 192.168.100.30 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=360;
}

# Сервера с java приложением
upstream cabinet {
ip_hash;
server 192.168.100.101 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=360;
}

# Балансировщик, если запрашивают / - отправляет на php, если /cabinet - на java приложение
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name example.com;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/site.ru.crt;
ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/site.ru.key;
ssl_protocols                   TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

   location / {
  proxy_pass http://php;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_503 http_504 http_502;
  proxy_connect_timeout 50;
  proxy_read_timeout 50;
  }

    location /cabinet {
  proxy_pass http://cabinet;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_503 http_504 http_502;
  proxy_connect_timeout 50;
  proxy_read_timeout 50;
  }
}

}
```

Comment: Но появилась необходимость вывести приложение из поддомена — зачем? Что бы огрести кучу проблем?

Comment: Вам придётся исправлять приложение, что бы в нём создавались правильные ссылки. nginx тут никак не поможет

Comment: сертификат на основной домен, на поддомен нет возможности купить.

Comment: Тогда только исправлять приложение.